# Link to a specific tab from another page

Tags: jquery, css, tabs, url-routing, hashcode

Some help would be appreciated - I'm trying to show a specific tab with a link from another page. Example shown [[here]](http://www.canberra.edu.au/media/asdf/home.html) The target page has most of the code - Bear in mind tabs work well as they are I just need to be able to target specific content within the tabs

Comment: Well since you need to know in jquery what page is requested you have to work with url first of all and get #tabx part then in your jquery code you can set that tab as current.

Comment: can you provide a working example? Thanks N.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
// remove current selection 
$(".tablist ul.tabs li").removeClass("current");

// check if the desired tab exists 
if ( $("#" + (window.location.hash.replace("#", ""))) ) {

    // selected desired tab
    $("#" + (window.location.hash.replace("#", ""))).addClass("current");

} else {

    // select first tab
    $('ul.tabs li:first').addClass('current');
}
```

Comment: Thanks Smamatti where does that code go? can you add it here? http://jsfiddle.net/SAvm5/1/

Comment: that's ok I just wanted to see where your block of code gets added with what I had so I can test it?

Comment: You should put it in your `target.html` (or link it from there), so it can execute it when the page is loaded. -- It replaces this line `$('ul.tabs li:first').addClass('current');`, but you will need to set this, when the hash is empty or not valid.

Comment: Updated the answer and the sample. This may not be the best solution, but it should work. -- http://jsfiddle.net/SAvm5/3/

Comment: what am I doing wrong? still not working - I have this '<a href="target.html#tab2" id="#tab2">Link to tab 2 on another page</a>' from the starting page am I missing something?

Comment: @NickP You added the script in your `home.html`. It needs to be in the `target.html`.

Comment: removed it and still doesn't work, unfortunately this code will have to be in a global script for all pages otherwise I'll have to add/remove whenever I need to link to a section of a tab...